# SQL Loader - No Terminator Found after Terminated

Tags: sql, database, oracle, loading, sql-loader

I'm trying to load records from SQL Loader but its giving me the error
no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field

Data File:

```
"00165332",11005,"S","N","N","Logitech Multimedia","لوجيتك مكبرات صوت متعددة الوسائط  Z50 دولفين لون وردي","E","A",12/17/2014 4:25:01 PM,"N","N","N","Y",267,"AE","S"
```

Control File:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE "/home/dmf/ITEMLOC.txt"
APPEND
INTO TABLE DMF.MIG_ITEM_LOC
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS

(
ITEM "SUBSTRB(:ITEM,1,25)",
LOC "TO_NUMBER(:LOC)",
LOC_TYPE "SUBSTRB(:LOC_TYPE,1,1)",
CLEAR_IND "SUBSTRB(:CLEAR_IND,1,1)",
TAXABLE_IND "SUBSTRB(:TAXABLE_IND,1,1)",
LOCAL_ITEM_DESC "SUBSTRB(:LOCAL_ITEM_DESC,1,250)",
LOCAL_SHORT_DESC "SUBSTRB(:LOCAL_SHORT_DESC,1,120)",
STORE_ORD_MULT "SUBSTRB(:STORE_ORD_MULT,1,1)",
STATUS "SUBSTRB(:STATUS,1,1)",
STATUS_UPDATE_DATE "TO_DATE(:STATUS_UPDATE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY  hh:mi:ss PM')",
STORE_PRICE_IND "SUBSTRB(:STORE_PRICE_IND,1,1)",
RPM_IND "SUBSTRB(:RPM_IND,1,1)",
EXT_UIN_IND "SUBSTRB(:EXT_UIN_IND,1,1)",
RANGED_IND "SUBSTRB(:RANGED_IND,1,1)",
PRIMARY_SUPP "TO_NUMBER(:PRIMARY_SUPP)",
PRIMARY_CNTRY "SUBSTRB(:PRIMARY_CNTRY,1,3)",
SOURCE_METHOD "SUBSTRB(:SOURCE_METHOD,1,1)"
)
```

It gives the error on LOCAL_SHORT_DESC which is Arabic
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table DMF.MIG_ITEM_LOC, column LOCAL_SHORT_DESC.
no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field

What could be the reason?

Comment: `Have you tried it without using the optionally enclosed by '"'

I mean,

just

load data ...
...
fields terminated by '~'
(
your columns
)` [see link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2201367?tstart=0)

Comment: just for fun, try puttin quotes on the date

Comment: Din't work in either of the cases. 

But when I replaced Arabic Text with any english text, it inserted the record. But it gives the same error if I place any arabic text

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. 
enclosed all the numeric fields also the date fields by ".

It loads successfully now.